# How to express "I'm at company"?

Tags: expressions

I know "I'm at home" and "I'm at school" are both native expresstions.

However, I googled "I'm at company" and just get about 16,700 results, which means it's not a common expression.

How will a native English speaker express this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I'm at _work_?

Comment: As @oerkelens said: either *I'm at work* or *I'm at the office* (or *I'm in the studio* or *garage* or wherever it is you do your work).

Comment: @DanBron, "I'm at the office" or "I'm at office"?

Comment: Definitely with *the*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say "I'm at work", and you can specify further with the type of building that your workplace is e.g. "I'm at the office" or "I'm at the construction yard"